# How to receive UPD struct data in Java sent from C program?

Tags: java, c, linux, sockets

This is received in program written in C:

```
struct cliprobe_data {
    unsigned char Apmac[6];
    unsigned short int Vendorid;
    unsigned short int Reserved1;
    unsigned char Bssid[6];
    unsigned char Radiotype;
    unsigned char Channel;
    unsigned char Associated;
    unsigned char Messagetype;
    char Timestamp[14];
    unsigned short int Reserved2;
    unsigned char Mutype;
    unsigned short int Reserved3;
    char Rssi;
    unsigned short int Reserved4;
    unsigned char Noisefloor;
    unsigned short int Reserved5;
    unsigned char Datarate;
    unsigned char MPDUflags;
    unsigned char Mumac[6];
    unsigned short int Framecontrol;
    unsigned short int Sequencecontrol;
    unsigned short int Reserved6;
```

};

How to do send in Java:

```java
DatagramPacket dpaket = (DatagramPacket) msg;
    ByteBuf bbBuf = dpaket.copy().content();
    byte[] byfs = new byte[bbBuf.readableBytes()];
    bbBuf.readBytes(byfs);
    System.out.println(new String(byfs, "UTF-8"));
```

The receive data is wrong:

[image]

I want to get `struct` data from c. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use `structs` as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Define a binary protocol in terms of octets, and then write yourself a library at each end, or in each language, to send and receive it. Using `structs` exposes you to half a dozen dependencies you don't need to be exposed to.

Comment: @EJP - Would a [`ProtocolBuffer`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) do well here? I'm not sure what OP would do for the interop. Maybe JNI?